# Rules for prices - do we have them?

Tags: discussion, editing

In our site, there are many prices listed. Can we create some rules for them to help people find price in text quickly?

For example, how is right:

- 10 USD
- $10
- $10 USD
- 10 USA dollars

How do we highlight them:

- Simple text
- *italic*
- **bold**
- ***italic bold***

What we do with currencies without currency symbol?
Should we use word `euro` or symbol `€`
[Here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/visiting-giant-panda-sanctuary-chengdu-from-guangzhou) the `¥` is presented - are we must to use such symbols for some currencies?
If yes, what are these currencies?

Update: how could this question being marked as duplicate, if it had had been asked much earlier?

Comment: Automatic formatting might be interesting (if tricky to implement), but a constraint on user behavior... I'm not sure that would have a desirable effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should currency symbols be written?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/how-should-currency-symbols-be-written)

Comment: @TRiG How does my question is a duplicate if it was asked before the linked one?

Answer (score 5):

Rules for prices - do we need them?

Is it necessary to set a rule for this? If you set rules, you need someone to enforce them. Otherwise there is no use having them.

I think that anything should be fine as along as it is intelligible and as long as there is no typo.

Comment: I think that this can be important, and I'm ready to do all the work for enforcing it.

Comment: Can you explain why it is important?

Comment: to help people find price in text quickly, as I've said. Currently I have real problems with that, and want to change this.

Answer (score 2):

## When writing

When writing a post you should use whichever format is clear enough and easy enough for you to write. That may (or may not) include the currency symbol if it is present on your keyboard or you know how to generate it. That may include three letter codes such as *EUR*. That may include plain text forms such as *US dollars*. All of these should be equally valid in my opinion.

*Eur* is a non-standard format (as are *EURO* and others), and should thus not be used.

Ideally, your post should look typographically ‘clean’; however, less ‘clean’ posts should not prevent people from upvoting (and vice-versa).

## When editing

An edit should typically include more than simply changing one variant to another variant. I admit I am guilty of suggesting a too minor edit here (which was rejected). However, the second edit was equally minor and should have been rejected, too. (Note that the second edit introduced the format symbol-value which, at least for Germany, is less common than value-symbol. Unfortunately I could not find definite sources which types are common/preferred in Germany, let alone in Austria and Slovakia.)

When changing other things within the text, performing a clean-up to adhere to typographic ideals can be warranted, as it is for capitalisation (e.g. *I*).

## From a typesetting perspective

From a typesetting point of view, I would definitely prefer the corresponding currency symbols **as long as it is clear which currency is meant.** Using € for Euro is unambiguous. Using $ is generally ambiguous, it could be Australian, US, Canada, New Zealand, Fiji … However, if the post is clearly about getting from (say) Atlanta, Georgia to Washington DC, then it is unambiguous enough that US-dollars are meant.

Using three-letter codes can be preferable in ambiguous cases, such as when going from the US to Canada. Using the written words should be restricted to cases where the number is also written out (‘a dollar or two’).

Whichever format<sup>[1]</sup> you use for writing the unit, **the same format** should be used for the number. This makes things that belong together look like they belong together. Examples:

> <strike>`EUR` 45</strike>
>
> <strike>EUR `45`</strike>
>
> EUR 45
>
> `EUR 45`
>
> `€45`
>
> €45
>
> <strike>`€`45</strike>
>
> <strike>€`45`</strike>

It is usually preferable to use simple plain text rather than code markup, since code markup disrupts one’s flow of reading. However, that effect may be desired in given circumstances — if it is used, both number and unit should be formatted using monospace.

In English texts,<sup>[2]</sup> the three-letter code should *preceed* the currency value as should the currency symbol. The three-letter code should be separated by a no-break space, which can be either directly entered or entered as `&nbsp;`. (A normal space often does no harm but can cause line breaks between currency and value which should be avoided.) According to typical English language style guides, **the currency symbol should not be separated by a space.**<sup>[3]</sup> Examples:

> EUR 45
>
> €45

In most other European languages, the currency typically *follows* the value. For example, the following variants are preferred in German:<sup>[4]</sup>

> 45 EUR
>
> 45 €

From a typesetting perspective, both styles are in-line with at least one standard. As long as there is no mixing between the two styles, an edit to convert the continental one into the English one should be avoided. Again, when editing anyway, there is no harm done in harmonising to the English standard.

---

**Notes:**

[1]: *Format* here is taken to mean *plain text*, `monospace`, MathJax, etc. (although the latter is not active on travel.SE).

[2]: And Irish, Latvian and Maltese, among the languages of the EU. Probably in many other languages outside Europe, too.

[3]: Compare the [style guide of the European Union](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-370303.htm), English version.

[4]: Compare the [style guide of the European Union](http://publications.europa.eu/code/de/de-370303.htm), German version.

Comment: Since I didn’t know this existed, I am [shamelessly copypasting my answer from the other question here](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/3737)

Answer (score 0):

I think, we should use such riles:

Highlight in italic, with currency symbol ahead, if any, and currency word (short or full) after.

Like this:

- *$10 USD*
- *$10 CAD*
- *10 RUR*

Currency symbols are being got from [Unicode table](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/currency_symbols.html)

Comment: I agree with this: [currency symbol][currency amounnt] [currency code - three letters]

Comment: If I had to set a rule, I would not dictate the use of symbols. They only exist for a handful of currencies. Use ISO4217.

Comment: Requiring currency symbols could cause irritation for PC users; AFAIK the only way to "type" those symbols is to use Character Map or to enter the Unicode code (assuming you happen to know what it is).

Comment: "$10 USD" is pleonasm, as both `$` and `D` stand for dollars.

Comment: @vartec which kind of dollars?

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 Doesn't matter, "$10" is read «ten dollars». "USD" is read «U.S. dollars», thus "$10 USD" would be read «ten dollars U.S. dollars», which sounds weird to say the least.

Comment: This rule goes against typographic conventions.